# How to extract, rename and view some log files from user inputed tar filename?

Tags: linux, bash, scripting

The problem is like this :

1. I need to extract the logs from a tar archive using user input/argument for the file name (cubelog_457890.tar)
2. In the archive there is just one folder named tftpboot that I need to rename to the original user input.
3. After that I need to open and view the log files.

```
#!/bin/bash
fname=$1

if [ -f $fname ]; then 
tar -xvzf $fname
fi

mv tftpboot $fname
```

If I try to use the script with the argument `cubelog_457890.tar` I have the problem that the MV line will not work.
Starting the script again and using `cubelog_457890` will do the job.

How can I make the MV command take cubelog_457890 from user input without the tar extension?

```
./extract.sh cubelog_457890.tar - will extract but not rename
./extract.sh cubelog_457890 - will rename the folder
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
#!/bin/bash
fname=$1

if [[ -f "${fname}.tar" ]]; then 
tar -xvf "${fname}.tar"
fi

mv tftpboot $fname
```

then `./extract.sh cubelog_457890`

Comment: You should quote all instances of `$fname` with double quotes.

Comment: And ideally use the `${fname}` syntax ...

Comment: It won't do anything like this, not even extract the tar file.

Comment: I edited the answer and tested OK.